# To remove the first character ' (single quote)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Can someone help me with my issue in removing first character ' from the data in informatica.I tried using LTRIM it didnt work, as the trimset was ' ,not sure how this will go with the quotes. I mean a quotes within quotes. Please advise which can help me remove the first character ' from the data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some more information might be needed. Where is the quote coming from? Is it in the input data or showing up in the header?

If it is the first case, you may try to follow up this [guide](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/22370?language=en_US) and use below formula:

```
REPLACECHR (1, INPUT, CHR(39), NULL )
```